# Perform sanity check before running tests with pytest

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I would like to perform some sanity check when I run tests using `pytest`. Typically, I want to check that some executables are accessible to the tests, and that the options provided by the user on the command-line are valid.

The closest thing I found was to use a fixture such as:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def sanity_check(request):
  if not good:
     sys.exit(0)
```

But this still runs all the tests. I'd like for the script to fail before attempting to run the tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to validate the command line options explicitly; this will be done by the arg parser which will abort the execution early if necessary. As for conditions checking, you are not far from the solution. Use

- [`pytest.exit`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-exit) to to an immediate abort
- [`pytest.skip`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-skip) to skip all tests
- [`pytest.xfail`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-xfail) to fail all tests (this is an expected failure though, so it won't mark the whole execution as failed)

Example fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def precondition():
    if not shutil.which('spam'):
        # immediate shutdown
        pytest.exit('Install spam before running this test suite.')
        # or skip each test
        # pytest.skip('Install spam before running this test suite.')
        # or make it an expected failure
        # pytest.xfail('Install spam before running this test suite.')
```

#### `xdist` compatibility

Invoking `pytest.exit()` in the test run with `xdist` will only crash the current worker and will not abort the main process. You have to move the check to a hook that is invoked before the runtestloop starts (so anything before the `pytest_runtestloop` hook), for example:

```
# conftest.py
def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    if not shutil.which('spam'):
        # immediate shutdown
        pytest.exit('Install spam before running this test suite.')
```

Comment: `pytest.exit()` does not seem to work with `pytest-xdist`, but the others are fine.

Comment: @Eric yes, `xdist` reimplements the runtestloop, so calling `pytest.exit()` will only crash the worker, but have no effect on main process. The answer in that case is to move the checks outside of the runtestloop; see update in the answer.

Comment: If you want to exit based on command line arguments that are passed around as fixtures without needing to validate them redundantly, I'm not sure using `pytest_sessionstart()` is possible.

Comment: If you mean accessing the argument values in fixture via `request.config.getoption('myarg')`, you can do the same via `session.config.getoption('myarg')` in the hook as well. Skipping vs immediate abort then only depends on how expensive it is to keep the suite running.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I also see that you can pass in a function to `parser.addoption()` for type validation, as well. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, `parser.addoption` shadows the `argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument`, so `type` is the same as in the stdlib: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run sanity check before whole test scenario then you can use conftest.py file - https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/plugins.html?highlight=re

Just add your function with the same scope and autouse option to conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def sanity_check(request):
  if not good:
     pytest.exit("Error message here")
```